# Program will stop once five even numbers are placed in array

Tags: c, arrays

This is a program that gets numbers input. From the numbers given or inputted, store in an array those numbers only that are even. Input will stop/terminates once 5 even numbers are already stored in the array. So here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
int num[5];
int x, counter, even[5], numEven=0;



    for(counter=0; counter<5; counter++){ //loop for getting the numbers from the user
        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num[counter]);
            if(num[counter]%2==0){                //storing the even numbers
                even[numEven] = num[counter];
                numEven++;
            }
    }




    printf("\n\nEven numbers: "); //printing even numbers
    for(counter=0; counter<numEven; counter++){
        printf("%d, ", even[counter]);
    }


getch();
return 0;
}
```

I have confusion in the part where will I stop the inputting when there's already 5 even numbers stored. Is there something missing? Or am I doing the wrong way? I hope I can get help and suggestions with the code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it stop with an error? Also, I was not able to locate where did you initialize your `x` variable. If it has value == 0, your outer loop will only execute once.

Comment: you have two nested loops that use the same variable `counter`. this is bad.

Comment: No... It will stop asking if you already inputted 5 even numbers. @mauren

Comment: You have a couple of things wrong or missing. You can't use `counter` as the variable for the first two loops at the same time (`for(counter=0...){ for(counter=0;){`). (It's fine to use it again in the last one that does `printf()`, because that's outside the first `for` loop.) You also have no exit condition for your loop when `numEven` reaches 5 (one of your first two `if` statements should be a `while` based on the value of `numEven`).

Comment: what is the question? the code (after you have edited it) stores exactly five numbers in the `num` array, and at most five numbers in the `even` array. it will terminate after all five numbers are entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
   int x, even[5], numEven = 0;

   while (numEven < 5)
   {
      scanf("%d", &x);
      if (x % 2 == 0)
      {
         even[numEven++] = x;
      }
   }
   printf("\n\nEven numbers: "); //printing even numbers
   for(x=0; x<numEven; x++)
   {
     printf("%d, ", even[x]);
   }
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

You keep readin inputs till `numEven` reaches 5. If the read input is an even number store it in the array and increment `numEven`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop if the number of times the program will ask the user for input is not fixed and dependent on the user's input.

```
while (numEven < 5) {
   printf("Enter number: ");
   scanf("%d", &num[counter]);
   if (num[counter] % 2 == 0) {
       even[numEven] = num[counter];
       numEven++;
   }
}
```